# Loop unrolling in inlined functions in C

Tags: c, optimization, inline, icc

I have a question about C compiler optimization and when/how loops in inline functions are unrolled.

I am developing a numerical code which does something like the example below.  Basically, `my_for()` would compute some kind of stencil and call `op()` to do something with the data in `my_type *arg` for each `i`.  Here, `my_func()` wraps `my_for()`, creating the argument and sending the function pointer to `my_op()`... who’s job it is to modify the `i`th double for each of the (`arg->n`) double arrays `arg->dest[j]`.

```
typedef struct my_type {
  int const n;
  double *dest[16];
  double const *src[16];
} my_type;

static inline void my_for( void (*op)(my_type *,int), my_type *arg, int N ) {
  int i;

  for( i=0; i<N; ++i )
    op( arg, i );
}

static inline void my_op( my_type *arg, int i ) {
  int j;
  int const n = arg->n;

  for( j=0; j<n; ++j )
    arg->dest[j][i] += arg->src[j][i];
}

void my_func( double *dest0, double *dest1, double const *src0, double const *src1, int N ) {
  my_type Arg = {
    .n = 2,
    .dest = { dest0, dest1 },
    .src = { src0, src1 }
  };

  my_for( &my_op, &Arg, N );
}
```

This works fine.  The functions are inlining as they should and the code is (almost) as efficient as having written everything inline in a single function and unrolled the `j` loop, without any sort of `my_type Arg`.

Here’s the confusion: if I set `int const n = 2;` rather than `int const n = arg->n;` in `my_op()`, then the code becomes as fast as the unrolled single-function version.  So, the question is: why?  If everything is being inlined into `my_func()`, why doesn’t the compiler see that I am literally defining `Arg.n = 2`?  Furthermore, there is no improvement when I explicitly make the bound on the `j` loop `arg->n`, which should look just like the speedier `int const n = 2;` after inlining.  I also tried using `my_type const` everywhere to really signal this const-ness to the compiler, but it just doesn't want to unroll the loop.

In my numerical code, this amounts to about a 15% performance hit.  If it matters, there, `n=4` and these `j` loops appear in a couple of conditional branches in an `op()`.

I am compiling with icc (ICC) 12.1.5 20120612.  I tried `#pragma unroll`. Here are my compiler options (did I miss any good ones?):

`-O3 -ipo -static -unroll-aggressive -fp-model precise -fp-model source -openmp -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -Winline -pedantic`

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking at the generated code?

Comment: How "far away" to look for values that are known at compile-time when inlining is a difficult decision. It looks like you ran into the compiler's limit. Passing `n` as an explicit function parameter might improve the odds.

Comment: I wonder if it would not gain much more speed if you swap the dimensions. As given now, you possibly take little advantage about cache-lines and burst fills (and you can use memcpy, which is highly optimized already). Also, filling the struct with an intializer is a gcc extension (hope you are aware of this - not a problem for me).

Comment: @Olaf There are quite a few additional calculations and conditionals in the real simulation code -- all of which happen to be independent of j and don't need to be recalculated.  While N~1024^3, this actually gives an order of magnitude speed up over the reverse.  Thanks about the struct initializer info, I did not know that.  Luckily icc doesn't seem to mind...

Comment: How are you determining that the `inline` functions are being inlined by the compiler?  By the way I thought this article interesting though a bit old, [Dr. Dobbs - The New C: Inline Functions](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-inline-functions/184401540) describing some of the compiler actions.

Comment: @Richard Chambers Well, I am using the `-Winline` option and not getting the "inline not honored" warnings that I do when I generate profiler code.  However, most clearly: the performance with `int const n=2;` is identical to that of a function in which I explicitly inlined and unrolled the inner loop.  This is about 15% faster than when I set `int const n=arg->n;`.  Thanks for the article, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: Well, it should not if running in gnu99-mode - a mode which implies gcc extensions. I did not talk about recalculation, but about selection the optimal sequence with regards of stack and memory interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, obviously the compiler isn't 'smart' enough to propagate the `n` constant and unroll the `for` loop. Actually it plays it safe since `arg->n` can change between instantiation and usage.

In order to have consistent performance across compiler generations and squeeze the maximum out of your code, do the unrolling by hand.

What people like myself do in these situations (performance is king) is rely on macros.

Macros will 'inline' in debug builds (useful) and can be templated (to a point) using macro parameters. Macro parameters which are compile time constants are guaranteed to remain this way.

Comment: C Preprocessor macros are a pain in the neck when using a debugger.  Macros are macros and not templates even if there some types of behavior they appear to share. You don't template macros you just provide arguments even if using macros within macros. Macros are expanded by the C Preprocessor to generate text that is then fed into the C compiler.  It is 1970s technology borrowed from even older assembler macros technology. Templates are built into the C++ compiler allowing access to compiler functionality and data not available to the C Preprocessor.

Comment: @RichardChambers: I agree for the comparsion to templates. However, macros OTOH allow for things you cannot do with templates. Such as creation for identifiers, declarations, etc. I think both have their usage, one should just be careful when using them. And as C does not have templates, you have to use macros for what they provide.

Comment: @egur: Hmm, to encourage icc to not play it safe, I declared `my_type`'s `n` as `const`, as well as the instance of the struct itself.  Once inlined, you'd figure it's just as immutable as the `n` in `my_op()`.  But, as I understand from what Adrian said, the fact that memory has been allocated for `Arg`, thus necessarily also for `Arg.n`, that prevents it from being optimized it out.  Anyways, you win for the macro idea.  I've only dabbled before, but in the last few hours I've gone macro crazy and used them to generate multiple versions of these functions... and got that 15% back.

Comment: Not that I recommend one capability over another, macros are not a solution for everything but are the the closest thing to templates the C language has to offer. Using them wisely can lead to both readable C code w/o loosing performance. With Visual C++ I have no debugger issues with them.

Answer (score 2):

It's faster, because your program does not assign memory to the variable.

If you don't have to perform any operations on unknown values they are treated as if they were `#define constant 2` with type checking. They are just added while the compilation.

Could you please chose one of the two tags (I mean C or C++), it's confusing, because the languages treat `const` values differently - C treats them like normal variables which value just can't be changed, and in C++ they do or don't have memory assigned depending on the context (if you need their address or if you need to compute them when the program is running, then memory is assigned).

Source: "Thinking in C++". No exact quote.

Comment: What do you mean by "that should have been a comment"?

Comment: I get it. But I can't post comments since i still haven't 50 points.

Comment: Well, it should have been a comment instead of an answer. At least parts of it (it really is a bit unstructured).

Comment: OK. I'll chcange the structure a little

Comment: Thanks. They are separated now.

Comment: The person who asked the question already changed the tags. So the question is not needed. But I won't change my answer, because it' would not fit the question anymore without the comment. Better said - I don't know how to change it without losing the sense of it.

Comment: You can comment now, so just remember next time. Apparently, you question has attracted two upvotes.